# Sorted Array to Balanced Binary Search Tree without recursion

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I was asked a question in an interview to construct a balanced binary search tree from a sorted array with recursion and without recursion. I was able to come up with a solution using recursion but failed to come up with a solution without recursion. Can anyone provide a solution to this problem without using recursion?

Comment: Please state which language you are working with, and add a tag for that language.

Comment: Recursions can always be transformed to a loop with help of a stack.

Comment: @AndrewMyers this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 2):

You can create and use your own stack (e.g., as an array or a linked list) and access it from inside a loop.

Each cell in the array or list will need to store the essential information about your tree that would otherwise be maintained by the recursive functions.

Some information from your recursive version (such as a depth counter) may be handleable by local variables instead. For some problems, you may be able to move *all* such information out of your stack into local variables; in such cases, you don't need an explicit stack at all...